# Python Classes and Iteration

Tags: python, class, iteration

I'm using the standard Python mailbox module to read messages from a Maildir.  Once read, I parse them and store the results in a dict.  I've put this functionality into a class and use `__getitems__` to enable other components of my program to access them. This works nicely and I'm happy that my code is both functional and readable.

My problem is how to turn this from a class that parses one message at a time into something that iterates over each message in the Maildir. One easy solution is to put a for loop in the main program and use the mailbox.iterkeys:

```
inbox = mailbox.Maildir('Maildir')
for key in inbox.iterkeys():
    mailparse.process(inbox, key)
```

This works but to me it doesn't seem very neat.  I'd expect to have all the maildir related functionality within the class rather than having to pass each maildir key into it. Something like:

```
class mailparse():
    def __init__(self, mdirpath):
        inbox = mailbox.Maildir(mdirpath)

    def __getitems__(self, key):
        return self.dictionary[key]

    def process():
        for key in inbox.iterkeys()
            ....

for x in Mailprocess:
    ....
```

Obviously my above code doesn't work but I'm thinking there must a solution along these lines to entirely self-contain the block of functionality within the class.

Comment: do you know about [generators](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)?

Comment: Do not use the same class for both a record and a collection of records. Your maildir iterator should return mailparse objects.

Comment: As an aside, I don't think `__getitems__` (note the 's') can work; it's [`__getitem__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__).

Comment: @thg435 I've read about generators during my search for answers to this problem but couldn't relate them to it.  The generator examples I've seen tended to focus on recursive arithmetic operations.

Comment: @FrancisAvila I think you're describing the solution I already have, where the keys iteration happens outside the mailparse object. This worked fine and I'm not convinced it was wrong.I can write functional code in Python but am still struggling to understand the best way to structure it. I don't want to create classes just for the sake of it but leave myself in doubt sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

I'd set this up very differently. If you really want an iterable class to handle this,

```
class MailboxParser(object):
    def __init__(self, mbox):
        self.mbox = mbox

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._process(key, self.mbox[key])

    def __iter__(self):
        for key, val in self.mbox.iteritems():
            yield self._process(key, val)

    def _process(self, key, content):
        """Do whatever on a single message"""
```

The `__iter__` member allows you to do

```
for x in MailboxParser(mbox):
    # now x is the result of processing a single message
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is exactly the answer I was searching for.  When you say, "If you really want an iterable class", are you suggesting that perhaps this isn't the method I should be using?

Comment: @SteveCrook: I don't know your exact requirements, but a simple freestanding function might do the trick just as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to make a derivated class from Maildir :

```
class Mailparse(mailbox.Maildir):
    def process(self):
       for key in self.itertkeys():
          # do what you need with your key...

my_mailparser = Mailparse('Maildir')
my_mailparser.process()
```

you will use it like a `mailbox.Maildir` except that it has a new method `process` that will do... whatever you need to do with all the keys ;)